# Lookup for the first non-zero value in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

If I have a data of 1's and 0's how can I return the variables with the first non-zero value in each row (Hlookup-in excel). Below is an example of the data and output needed. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
    a b c d output
p   1 0 0 0   a
q   0 0 1 1   c
r   0 1 0 0   b
s   0 0 0 1   d
```

Answer (score 2):

Use VNAME and WHICHN functions together with an Array. 
There are various ways to simplify the listing of variables, see the documentation here http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/68089/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0wphcpsfgx6o7n1sjtqzizp1n39.htm

```
Array list_vars(*) a b c d e;
X = whichn(1, of list_vars(*);
Variable_Name = vname(list_vars(x));
```

Edit:
If a row is all zeroes then x=0, and variable remains blank.

```
Variable_Name = ifn(x=0, ' ', vname(list_vars(x));
```

Comment: Can we use a do while or any other loop?

Comment: If you wanted that would be a way to do so.

Comment: what if there are no 1 s in the row? its throwing an error

Comment: Make the second assignment conditional.  `if x then variable_name=vname(list_vars(x));`

Comment: What's the value of X then? What do you want to get returned, execute the vname function conditionally using an If or IFN.

Answer (score 0):

One brute force method uses `case`:

```
proc sql;
    select (case when q <> 0 then 'q'
                 when r <> 0 then 'r'
                 when s <> 0 then 's'
                 when t <> 0 then 't'
            end) as FirstNonzero
    from t;
```

Comment: But there may be many q,r,s,t s...I just need to search the first non zerop value and return the variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
a b c d output
```

p   1 0 0 0   a
q   0 0 1 1   c, d
r   0 1 0 0   b
s   0 0 0 1   d

Answer:

```
array list(*) a b c;
array var(3) $ x1-x3;
do i=1 to dim(list);
if list{i}>0 then var(i)=vname(list{i});
end;
output=catx(", ",of var(*));
```

Comment: This seems to be answer to a different question as it is producing a list of variables with 1 instead of just the first variable with a 1. Note there is no need for the second array. Just move the CATX() function into the IF/THEN statement.